# Closing modal with submit button and close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I managed to get my modal to close using the X button but I'm trying to do the same thing for the submit button but can seem to get that to work.

This is what I tried

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">&#x2715;</a>
     <button onclick = "writeData(); getData();" href="#close" id="submitButton"> Submit </button>
```

```
.bodyclose {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog:target > .bodyclose {
    display:block;
}
```

Basically what it comes down to for closing the modal using the "x" I used CSS.

For the submit I tried using jQuery:

```
        <SCRIPT>
            $('#submitButton').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#openModal').modal('hide');
                return false;
            });
        </SCRIPT>
```

I can't seem to make the `submitButton` the register the function. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `href` with `<button>`.

Use `<button onclick="window.location.href = '#close';">Submit</button>`
Instead of `<button onclick = "writeData(); getData();" href="#close" id="submitButton"> Submit</button>`.
Here is the full code:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">&#x2715;</a>
     <button onclick="window.location.href = '#close';"> Submit </button>
```

```
.bodyclose {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog:target > .bodyclose {
    display:block;
}
```